# How to run text contect in HTML as JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a site with Pjax, so I have to reload some scripts every time open a new page. These page may contain/need different JavaScript, I hope to write the script this page needed in somewhere like `<script id="balabala">alert("hello");</script>`, and when pjax reload, it get the script text and run as JavaScript. Is this possible and how to make it work?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? If a page is loaded via ajax any JS within script tags should get executed just fine...

Comment: @Pablo It's Pjax, not ajax...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer myself:
Using eval() Function function, see: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp